# How can I decrease a key of a state in React without knowing the key name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have the following state in React:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState({foo: 1, bar: 1});
```

and I have data like

```
const data = [{who: "foo", otherVal: "bla"}, {who: "bar", otherVal: "bla"}];
```

If I remove an object from the data array, I want to decrease the counter by 1 related to the `who` value of the deleted object.

If `{who: "foo", otherVal: "bla"}` gets removed, I want to decrease the `foo` key of the `counter` because `who === "foo"`. But In my app I don't know that `foo` is `foo` or `bar` is `bar`. I must use `counter[data.who]` somehow to update my state.

Comment: `setCounter(counter => ({...counter, [entry.who]: counter[entry.who] - 1 }));` where `entry` is the entry being removed, see the linked question's answers for details. (Be sure to use the callback version of `setCounter` as shown, so you don't accidentally use stale state.)

Comment: The linked answer do not really help as I already know theses fundamentals. But your code helps and works. But to understand and read more about the details - is the `xx => ()` in the setter already the callback version? New to me to see an arrow there .

Comment: Yes, that's an arrow function being passed to the state setter, so React will call it with the up-to-date state value. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: When I google `callback version of usestate in react" I don't find any useful information. What is the more common term for that?

Comment: The documentation seems to like the term [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). I'd probably have looked for "callback version of the state setter" but no idea if that would have been more successful. :-)

Comment: Great! Thank you